# Android build.gradle file what is adbOptions method used for?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Google cant seem to help me. I am looking for the usage of adbOptions from the AppExtension class that the project file extends in build.gradle file.  Android application plugin declaration at the top of the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

delegates closures to AppExtension groovy class found [here](https://developer.android.com/shareables/sdk-tools/android-gradle-plugin-dsl.zip)

and in there i see it has a reference to a adbOptions method.  How do i use it, and what is its purpose ? i need to see a call for it in the build.gradle file so i can better understand it.

Comment: Are you using the discontinued https://github.com/jvoegele/gradle-android-plugin plugin?

Comment: no im referring to the one that is prepopulated when you create a new project.  so its: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using it to make the adb timeout period longer, to keep from getting `ShellCommandUnresponsiveException` as part of my build. Inside my `android` block I have:

```
android {
    adbOptions {
        timeOutInMs 30 * 1000
    }
}
```

because the timeout period is in ms. I have a custom task that deploys multiple flavors at the same time (with different `applicationId` values), and that kept timing out.

I don't know what else you can do with `adpOptions`. As you pointed out, the documentation is rather limited.